# How does gremlin step .dedup('from' , 'to'') works?

Tags: gremlin

Gremlin step `.dedup('from' , 'to')` remove elements with the same `from` **AND** `to` values or with the same `from` **OR** `to` values?

I need **AND** so I made that in this way:

```
.select('from' , 'to').as('hash').dedup('hash')
```

Comment: I can't help but think this would be something trivial to test?

Answer (score 1):

The strings provided to dedup() refer to as() labels used earlier in the traversal. There is an example here. http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#dedup-step

It's not really 'from' , 'to' as much as parts of the path history. As the example shows you can think of it as being an AND where if the same path segment appears more than once dedup('a','b') will remove it.